# embeded video gallery and bounce rate

Tags: seo, ranking, youtube, bounce-rate

Just a quick one - I am considering adding a type of video gallery page to my website with embedded videos from youtube, my own vids from my own youtube channel, which leads me to my question...

When user views a video, if they are like me, they are likely to click on the "*watch on youtube*" link, if this does happen, it will obviously result in a user having spent a very short amount of time on the page and then bouncing of to our youtube channel. Can this be considered a bad thing, in terms of SEO &/or rankings?

Comment: It has never been confirmed that bounce rate influences rankings directly, nor has there been any strong evidence to suggest otherwise. Low bounce rate indicates good content and in turn can indirectly improve SEO because people may link to it.

Comment: @SimonHayter yes and no.I suppose..so much conflicting information out there...I have read on a few different Q&A on here (forgive me for being to lazy to find the urls now) where users had written about their bounce rate decreasing by 10 or 20% only for their rankings to jump up for the better...now whether this was due to content being improved is debatable..but then again major sites such as SEJ has bounce featured as one of the most important aspects...so WHO or rather WHAT to believe? I personally believe good ol' long decent content is best, so I am very hesitant over this video idea..